# ASUS HDMI dual monitor not working with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell xps 15 and everything seems to be working well until I try to plug in my ASUS HDMI monitor to the HDMI port on my laptop to run dual monitors. When I do so, the image appears fine on both screens but Ubuntu freezes and I have to hard restart my computer.
My laptop is also touch screen so I don't know if this affects anything.

I am somewhat new to Ubuntu but this is the kernal version that I am running: 4.13.0-32-generic

What should I try to get my dual monitor working properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It turns out that a simple sudo-apt get update and sudo-apt get upgrade fixed my issue.